# Symfony 4: Form as service, inject service : too few arguments

Tags: php, symfony4

I try to get service in my Form, following official instructions:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_dependencies.html

this is my services.yaml:

```
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false      
class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

App\Service\:
    resource: '../src/Service/*'

App\Form\:
    resource: '../src/Form/*'
```

my form look like this :

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;

use App\Entity\Contrat;
use App\Entity\Society;
use App\Entity\Client;
use App\Form\DataTransformer\ClientToNumberTransformer;
use App\Form\DataTransformer\SocietyToNumberTransformer;



class ContratType extends AbstractType{

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(SocietyToNumberTransformer $manager){ // this is the breakpoint from error
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('...')
            ...
        ;
        // Old fashion way for testing only ...
        $builder->get('client')->addModelTransformer(new ClientToNumberTransformer($this->manager));
        $builder->get('society')->addModelTransformer(new SocietyToNumberTransformer($this->manager));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver){
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Contrat::class,
        ));
    }
```

It's look-like pretty ... When i test this with postman I get this error :

> Too few arguments to function App\Form\ContratType::__construct(), 0
>   passed in /code/vendor/symfony/form/FormRegistry.php on line 92 and
>   exactly 1 expected

I don't understand, i found my fomr in autowiring debug command :

```
php bin/console debug:autowiring
```

> App\Form\ContratType
>   App\Form\DataTransformer\ClientToNumberTransformer
>   App\Form\DataTransformer\SocietyToNumberTransformer

and the controller :

```
  public function addContrat(Request $request, FormData $formData){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');

        $data = $formData->getRequestData($request);
        var_dump($data);

        $contrat = new Contrat;
        $form = $this->factory->createBuilder(ContratType::class, $contrat)->getForm();

        $form->submit($data);

        if($form->isValid()){
            $em->persist($contrat);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->response(
                $this->serialize(
                    $contrat, 
                    ['group1']
                )
            );
        }
        return $this->response('error', 500);
    }
```

thx for your help.

Comment: Where's the route which you request with Postman?

Comment: the root who call the controller where instanciate my form ... look like /api/contrat/add

Comment: Code inside controller, can we __see it__?

Comment: i have add this ;)

Comment: $contrat = new Contrat; You are creating an object without parameters.

Comment: it's for tests ... $contrat = new Contrat; You are creating an object without parameters. Yeap, is not a problem ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace

```
$form = $this->factory->createBuilder(ContratType::class, $contrat)->getForm();
```

for

```
$form = $this->createForm(ContratType::class, $contrat);
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html#creating-form-classes

I have got the same problem but as I build my form from inside a service, I m still stuck ;-)

Hope it helps